# Suppose $M$ has trivial 1-st de Rham cohomology group. For which integers $k$ does there exist a smooth map $f : M → T^n$ of degree $k$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact oriented smooth $n$-manifold, with $H_{dR}^1(M)=0$.
For which integers $k$ does there exist a smooth map $f : M → T^n$ of degree $k$?

I know that if $M$ is simply-connected, we can lift the map to the universal cover, and then conclude that $k=0$.

However, not every $M$ with $H_{dR}^1(M)=0$ is simply-connected. Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Same proof. Use the algebraic assumption to show that the image of $\pi_1(M)$ in $\Bbb Z^3$ is zero.

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you mean that I can use the lifting criterion? But I really do not know the algebraic method to show the image of $\pi_1$ is zero. Can you give me some hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can still lift through the universal cover, because the image of any homomorphism $\pi_1(M) \to \Bbb Z^n$. It factors through $H_1(M)$ since $\Bbb Z^n$ is abelian, and kills the torsion subgroup of $H_1(M)$ because $\Bbb Z^n$ is torsion free. $H_1(M)/\text{Tors}(M) \cong \Bbb Z^{b_1}$, and your assumption is precisely that $b_1=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand why it "kills the torsion subgroup of $H_1(M)$ because $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is abelian"?

Comment: @APRT Typo. Meant torsion-free

Answer (score 1):

The de Rham cohomology ring of the $n$-dimensional torus is the Grassmann algebra $\bigwedge\mathbf Z^n$ and is generated by elements of degree $1$. If $f\colon M\rightarrow T^n$ is a differentiable map, then the induced morphism of algebras
$$
f^\star\colon H_{dR}^\star(T^n)\rightarrow H_{dR}^\star(M)
$$
is zero in degree $1$ since $H_{dR}^1(M)=0$ by assumption. It follows that $f^\star$ is zero in degree $n$ as well. Hence, the degree of $f$ is zero too.